# How to build DataFrame from two dicts Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a dataframe, in which this attempt grabs `data` and `column` from `dicts`. (I tried doing this with `pd.Series` but I kept running into issues there, as well.)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get link and parse
page = requests.get('https://www.finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&ft=4')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# return 'Title's for each filter
# to be used as columns in dataframe
titles = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'screener-combo-title'})
title_list = []
for t in titles:
    t = t.stripped_strings
    t = ' '.join(t)
    title_list.append(t)
title_list = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(title_list)}

# finding filters-cells tag id's
# to be used to build url
filters = soup.find_all('select', attrs={'data-filter': True})
filter_list = []
for f in filters:
    filter_list.append(f.get('data-filter'))

# finding selectable values per cell
# to be used as data in dataframe
final_list = []
for f in filters:
    options = f.find_all('option', attrs={'value': True})
    option_list = []    # list needs to stay inside
    for option in options:
        if option['value'] != "":
            option_list.append(option['value'])
    final_list.append(option_list)
final_list = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(final_list)}


df = pd.DataFrame([final_list], columns=[title_list])
print(df)
```

This results in `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` An example would look like (the first column is NOT the index):

```
Exchange    Index     ...
amex     s&p500     ...
nasd     djia
nyse
```

Comment: Your variable `filters` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt to build a dict where key corresponds to filter values, and value corresponds to a list of possible choices. Does it suit your needs?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get link and parse
page = requests.get('https://www.finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&ft=4')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

all_dict = {}
filters = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'filters-cells'})
for i in range(len(filters) // 2):
    i_title = 2 * i
    i_value = 2 * i + 1
    sct = filters[i_title].find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'screener-combo-title'})
    if len(sct)== 1:
        title = ' '.join(sct[0].stripped_strings)      
        values = [v.text for v in filters[i_value].find_all('option', attrs={'value': True}) if v.text]
        all_dict[title] = values

max_element = max([len(v) for v in all_dict.values()])
for k in all_dict:
    all_dict[k] = all_dict[k] + [''] * (max_element - len(all_dict[k]))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_dict)
```

Comment: When I do `df = pd.DataFrame([all_dict])` it returns this shape: `[1 rows x 63 columns]`. From my understanding, passing in a dict would create a column per key with the rows being filled by the values. Same result when I do `.from_dict` as well. Perhaps I'm building the df wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what DataFrame you want to create: you have different numbers of values for each column. You want a list of `pd.Series`?

Comment: Here is an example:

Comment: data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}; 
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

Comment: The dataframe example is posted near the bottom of my post.

Comment: I also went over that I did try `pd.Series` in the second sentence. I either get back that arrays aren't equal numbers or it's the wrong shape.

Comment: Ok, so you want a DataFrame with a number of rows that corresponds to the longest number of values filter proposed and fill the rest with empty string?

Comment: Yes. I'd figure it would either bring back `NaN` values which I could then change from there, but if there's a way to condense that step into the creation of the dataframe, that would be nice.